# iPhone view switching - curl transition

Tags: iphone, animation, transition

I'm loading a view in my app with the following code:

```
- (void)showPicker {
ImagePickerViewController *imagePickerView = [[ImagePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImagePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:imagePickerView animated:YES];
```

}

How can I load it with a curl up/curl down transition?

Thanks in advance,

Yassin

Comment: I don't think you can, since you're presenting a modal view controller, you're not switching views but controllers. I have just tested it with basic UIView animations and the `animated` parameter set to `NO`, but that did not work properly.

Comment: JoostK, you should put this in an answer so the system can process it. Right now, Yassin has no way to mark the question as answered if your correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the code you showed there, you could set the modalTransitionStyle property of imagePickerView. But, your possible values are (from the SDK documentation):

- **UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical**: When the view controller is presented, its view slides up from the bottom of the screen. On dismissal, the view slides back down. This is the default transition style.
- **UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal**: When the view controller is presented, the current view initiates a horizontal 3D flip from right-to-left, resulting in the revealing of the new view as if it were on the back of the previous view. On dismissal, the flip occurs from left-to-right, returning to the original view.
- **UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve**: When the view controller is presented, the current view fades out while the new view fades in at the same time. On dismissal, a similar type of cross-fade is used to return to the original view.

Your other option requires you to get a lot fancier. Let's assume the navigationController is the the root view controller of the application, and it's stored in a property of your application delegate called navigationController. You could implement the following methods:

```
- (void)curlInViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    self.curledViewController = viewController;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"curlInView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [self.navigationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)curlOutViewController {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"curlOutView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [self.curledViewController removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    if([animationID isEqualToString:@"curlOutView"]) {
        self.curlViewController = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I'm using the modalTransitionStyle property now, and tomorrow I'm going to implement the methods you posted above.

Answer (score 4):

This is now easily available in OS 3.2 and above; you do it like this: --

```
// if the legend button is tapped, curl up the map view to display the legend view underneath. 
- (IBAction) legendButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
    UIViewController *legend = [[LegendViewController alloc] init];
    legend.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    legend.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:legend animated:YES];  
    [legend release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I love these dormant questions.  I had a lot of success doing something like this where you use a view transition animation to show the new view and then presentModalViewController in the completionHandler so that your new view is treated as a modal view.

```
    UIView *container = self.view.window;
    [self.theNewViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    [UIView transitionWithView:container
                  duration:kAnimationViewTransition 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
                    [container addSubview: self.theNewViewController.view];
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self presentModalViewController:self.theNewViewController animated:NO];
                }
 ];
```